# Why is my 2010 MacBook Pro not detecting RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

I recently acquired a 2010 13" MacBook Pro. The computer beeps every 5 seconds (indicating no RAM is installed). I have tried installing four different compatible SODIMMs in both slots but nothing works. None of the slots work! Because both slots are not functional, the computer is useless. What could be causing the problem? What part of the slot might be damaged? I have tried adjusting the four screws surrounding the RAM slot with no luck. Suggestions?

Far fetched but has anyone had success with reflowing the RAM slot?

Comment: I'm guessing you've done an [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) reset?

Comment: @JMY1000 Yes, I have attempted both resets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that all the RAM you're trying is actually good, by installing each the SODIMMs in another machine. If the RAM is recognized, then it's OK.

If the RAM is good, then the memory modules are not being electrically connected to the motherboard in the Macbook (either because of a RAM socket problem, or a bad electrical connection(s) between the socket and the board), or there might be a failure within the electronics on the board.

If the RAM is good, the repair sounds like something that'd require professional attention. The Macbook may be considered "Vintage" or "Obsolete" by Apple; more information is on Apple's page [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624). If the machine is Vintage or Obsolete, Apple may decline to repair it and may further decline to provide replacement parts.

However, you may be able to find a non-Apple service provider who can examine and perhaps repair the fault(s), as repair may require no parts, or parts which can be sourced other than from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working screen, clean housing and working keyboard, it may be worthwhile to replace the motherboard as 2010 units with broken screens are available for very little money at this point. I've replaced 2011 motherboards, screens and keyboards affordably and am still using my 2011 17" matte as my primary road warrior.

Comment: Where did you find the cracked replacements?